# Why can't install the jboss/keycloak image be pulled?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to install KeyCloak using a Helm chart so I ran these two commands.

```sh
$ helm install codecentric/keycloak
$ helm install keycloak codecentric/keycloak
```

Then I checked pod status:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
keycloak-0   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          52s
```

Since there was an error, I checked detailed events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>         default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/keycloak-0 to node3
  Warning  Failed     24s               kubelet, node3     Failed to pull image "jboss/keycloak:9.0.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/jboss/keycloak:9.0.2": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/jboss/keycloak:9.0.2": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/jboss/keycloak/manifests/9.0.2: dial tcp 52.55.198.220:443: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed     24s               kubelet, node3     Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    23s               kubelet, node3     Back-off pulling image "jboss/keycloak:9.0.2"
  Warning  Failed     23s               kubelet, node3     Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    8s (x2 over 54s)  kubelet, node3     Pulling image "jboss/keycloak:9.0.2"
```

Why can't pull the image be pulled successfully?

Comment: firewalls blocking connection to internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment suggests, this seems to be a firewall related problem. I've just ran the same commands on a local minikube instance and it worked well.
Can your cluster pull other images from dockerhub?
You can ssh into any of your worker nodes and try to use `docker pull` to find out.

Comment: Yes, it's docker issue.

Comment: Please provide details about the issue. What specifically fixed it?